# My name is Mohammad, and i respect the name my parents had given but outside of home, people call me "Mo" what should i do?

Tags: sharia, naming

Assalamu-Aleikum It is surprising that even Some Muslims call me "Mo", I want this name to be respected and not just played around with . I also don't want to say this to them in a rude way. Please answer thank you very much.